# Why recyclerview is invisible ,gone or disappear whenever adapter call notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

Recyclerview is showing a data of sqlite database.
Recyclerview is gone, invisible or i don't know what happen whenever data is inserted into the sqlite database.

Activity Code:

```
MessageListRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.message_list_sender_list);
        myLastDbHandler=new MyDbHandler(MessageList.this,LAST_MESSAGE+".db",null,1);
        messageListAdapter=new MessageListAdapter(myLastDbHandler.sqlLastMessagesList(),MessageListRV,this,myLastDbHandler);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        MessageListRV.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        MessageListRV.setAdapter(messageListAdapter);
refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 messageListAdapter.updateData(myLastDbHandler.sqlMessagesList());
            }
        });
```

Adapter Code:

```
public void updateData(List<SqlMessages> sqlMessages)
    {
        this.userMessagesList=sqlMessages;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstantiating the collection on an adapter doesnt work you have to modify the collection

```
public void updateData(List<SqlMessages> sqlMessages)
    {
        if (userMessagesList.size > 0) userMessagesList.clear();
        userMessagesList.addAllsqlMessages),
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: This is clear the list and than recreate adapter ....i need only update

Comment: Still problem is not resolved ....RV is gone or invisible after call the updateData() method